# Converting LINQ Extension method to work with L2E

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on a search page where users are able to use wildcards `*` in their search criteria. The wildcard can be placed at the beginning, or end of a string. Since there are several fields I need this to be applied to, I figured an extension method would be the best way. The code I came up with currently works, but not with `IQueryable`.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> MyExtMethod(this IEnumerable<string> items, string searchString)
    {
        var searchType = -1;    
        if(searchString.IndexOf("*") == -1) //No wildcard
        {
            searchType = 0;
        }
        else if(searchString.IndexOf("*") == 0 && searchString.LastIndexOf("*") == searchString.Length - 1)//start and end
        {
            searchType = 1;
        }
        else if(searchString.IndexOf("*") == 0)//ends with
        {
            searchType = 2;
        }
        else if(searchString.LastIndexOf("*") == searchString.Length - 1) //starts with
        {
            searchType = 3;
        }

        var search = searchString.Replace("*", "");

        foreach(var i in items)
        {
            switch(searchType)
            {
                case 0: yield return i;
                break;
                case 1: if(i.Contains(search))
                            yield return i;
                break;
                case 2: if(i.EndsWith(search))
                            yield return i;
                break;
                case 3: if(i.StartsWith(search))
                            yield return i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only use string manipulation and extension methods that are already supported by L2E `Contains`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`. Can this be converted to work with entities? If so, what needs to be done? Thanks.

EDIT:
If possible, I would love to be able to use this as such:

```
db.SomeTable.Where(s => s.SomeField.MyExtMethod(somestring));
```

Bonus points for reference sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some base code around the [internet](http://trentacular.com/2010/08/linq-to-entities-wild-card-like-extension-method/) and modified it slightly to work as I need it to.

- abc   :  matches "abc" exactly
- *abc  :  matches if string ends with "abc"
- abc*  :  matches if string starts with "abc"
- *abc* :  matches if string contains "abc"

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> valueSelector,
    string value,
    char wildcard)
{
    return source.Where(BuildLikeExpression(valueSelector, value, wildcard));
}

        public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildLikeExpression<TElement>(
            Expression<Func<TElement, string>> valueSelector,
            string value,
            char wildcard)
        {
            if (valueSelector == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

            var method = GetLikeMethod(value, wildcard);

            value = value.Trim(wildcard);
            var body = Expression.Call(valueSelector.Body, method, Expression.Constant(value));

            var parameter = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetLikeMethod(string value, char wildcard)
        {
            var methodName = "Equals";

            var textLength = value.Length;
            value = value.TrimEnd(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = "StartsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }
            value = value.TrimStart(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = (methodName == "StartsWith") ? "Contains" : "EndsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }

            var stringType = typeof(string);
            return stringType.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { stringType });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

EF uses `IQueryable<T>` - not `IEnumerable<T>`

So something like this should do:

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static IQueryable<Table> SearchText(
    this IQueryable<Table> q,
    string searchString
  )
  {
    var searchType = -1;    
    if(searchString.IndexOf("*") == -1)
    {
        searchType = 0; // No wildcard
    }
    else if(searchString.IndexOf("*") == 0 &&
      searchString.LastIndexOf("*") == searchString.Length - 1)
    {
        searchType = 1; // start and end
    }
    else if(searchString.IndexOf("*") == 0)
    {
        searchType = 2; // ends with
    }
    else if(searchString.LastIndexOf("*") == searchString.Length - 1)
    {
        searchType = 3; // starts with
    }

    var search = searchString.Replace("*", "");

    switch(searchType)
    {
      default:
      case 0: return q.Where( o => o == search );
      case 1: return q.Where( o => o.Text.Contains( search ) );
      case 2: return q.Where( o => o.Text.EndsWith( search ) );
      case 3: return q.Where( o => o.Text.StartsWith( search ) );
    }
  }
}
```

Where `Table.Text` is the property you want to search.

Then you can use it like this:

```
IQueryable<Table> q = dbContext.Table;

var matches = q.SearchText( searchString ).ToList();
```

Comment: The loop is now redundant, isn't it??

Comment: @Gabe I agree your edit makes sense, but it changes the OP's logic

Comment: This solution seems that it will only work with one table type. Would it be possible to make this work given an unknown table? For example, I can do `db.SomeTable.Where(s => s.Contains(searchString))`. Can this be rewritten so be used with any string field for any table?

Comment: @Jeff yes, this is for searching one column of one table. If you want to generalize it, you need to look at building Expression Trees or using something like [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) that does it for you.

Comment: +1 for getting me started with expression trees to develop my solution